# Proof the bound for the Fourier coefficients: $|\hat{f}(n)| \leq Me^{-\delta|n|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

There are some uncertainty regarding how to get this bound for Fourier coefficients.

These are given:
Let $\delta > 0$ and $A_{\delta} = A(e^{-\delta}, e^{\delta}) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : e^{-\delta} \leq |z| \leq e^{\delta}\}$ be an annulus. Let $f(t) = g(e^{it})$ such that $g: A_{\delta} \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and $|g(z)| \leq M$ for some $M > 0$ and for all $z$ in this annulus.

To show: $|\hat{f}(n)| \leq Me^{-\delta|n|}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

When I try to prove this, I was wondering whether the information that is given to me is correct.
The set $A_{\delta}$ is not open, so I don't think I can represent $g$ as Laurent series
$$g(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}c_nz^n$$
where (by Cauchy integral formula)
$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}g(z)z^{-n-1}dz, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and $\Gamma$ is a closed curve inside the annulus. This is because a function is analytic in a domain that is open set, not closed I thought. So I try to fix it by defining a new set $A$ which is the given annulus, without the boundaries (so $e^{-\delta} < |z| < e^{\delta}$). Now I don't have the problem with expanding $g$ as Laurent series, but the problem is now finding the bound.

My lecturer suggests to use circles with radius $e^{\delta}$ and $e^{-\delta}$ and apply ML-inequality. But this circle is not in $A$ and I cannot use the given $A_{\delta}$.
So now I'm stuck, I would be happy if someone can help me.